# programmatically call a web service from a test application

Tags: wcf, load-testing

I am writing an test application to do a load test on my existing WCF service.
There can be numerous clients calling the WCF service. 
How do I write code to generate several clients calling the WCF service.

Any lead or forum or blog will immensely help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but [the WCF Load Test](http://wcfloadtest.codeplex.com/) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can load test web service using SOAP UI. Free Version is [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/loadui/files/)